# Using a different id name for Joomla forms

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, xml

I have a form in Joomla that uses XML:

```
    <form action="index.php?option=com_content&view=contents" method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm">
        <?php $this->form->renderFieldset("visitorDetails") ?>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('controller.send')" >Send</button>
    </form>
```

it works fine, the problem is that when i want to change the ID from `adminForm` to any other name, it won't work. Does Joomla only accept `adminForm` as ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most form views in core components have custom `Joomla.submitbutton()` functions. Standard function does indeed support only `adminForm` as form ID. Instead you can use `Joomla.submitform()` and pass your form:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="Joomla.submitform('controller.send', this.form)" >Send</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification.